# FORM-TAG not work

Tags: php, html, post, action

i try to send this form-tag to my page customer.php but it doesn´t send a post to customer.php
in customer.php $_POST is always NULL

```
<form action="customer.php" method="POST">
     <span id="MyCustomerDataHeader">MEINE KONTAKTDATEN</span><br><br><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Nachname:</label><input type="text"  name="secondname"  class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php print_r($query->getCustomerData()->secondname);?>"/><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Vorname:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" style="margin-left:15px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->firstname;?>"/><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" style="margin-left:30px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->email;?>" /><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Geburtstag:</label><input type="birthday" name="birthday" style="margin-left:-10px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->birthday;?>" /><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Handynummer:</label><input type="text" name="mobilephone" style="margin-left:-40px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->mobilephone;?>" /><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Stra&szlige:</label><input type="text" name="street" style="margin-left:15px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->street;?>" /><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Stadt:</label><input type="text" name="city" style="margin-left:30px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->city;?>" /><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Bundesland:</label><input type="text" name="federalestate" style="margin-left:-25px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->federalestate;?>"/><br>
     <label class="MyCustomerDataLabel">Land:</label><input type="text" name="country" style="margin-left:30px;" class="MyCustomerData" value="<?php echo $query->getCustomerData()->country;?>"/><br>
     <input type="submit" id="myCustomerDataButton" name="deleCustomer" style="font-size:14pt;margin-top:-5px;" value="ACCOUNT L&Ouml;SCHEN" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds very strange. Please open your browsers development console and examine the request done. It _should_ be a post request. What do you see?

Comment: i have put $_POST["secondname"] in var_dump() but it is always undefined and in the console i get this:<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: secondname in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\theroom\customer.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
NULL

Comment: That is not exactly an answer to my question above, is it?

Comment: contentscript.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedgetPageLang @ contentscript.js:21main @ contentscript.js:59(anonymous function) @ contentscript.js:78

Comment: my console show me this error

Comment: Still not what I asked about the requests content. But at least that shows that you have a serious client side issue. Probably you use some JS library like jQuery or similar for form processing and the library is not present. Something like that.

Comment: Start with a simple input field  .... Your value of the input fields should be checked before parsing .. Use php `isset` ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php ..

Comment: using `print_r` to output the value of `secondname` is liable to lead to problems

Comment: i have use isset , my POST exists but it is undefined